# How can customize chrome driver call only once for all scenario run in karate UI automation

Tags: karate

In my project I have created Login and logout features separately and calling them in background. Now for other modules test I put it them like:

```
        * call read('classpath:fdiPortalUI/loginCommon.feature')
        * configure afterScenario = function(){ karate.call('classpath:fdiPortalUI/logout.feature'); }
```

Its working fine.

In my module UI test feature login is called again and again after every scenarios available in particular feature, which I need to avoid and call login at start of feature file and logout at end of feature apart of scenario start and end.
Do we have any possibility for same or any customization available.